# squid proxies disabled ssh access, how to resolve

Tags: ssh, proxy, squid

After installing squid proxies I'm unable to assess my server via ssh over port 21.
Please help me to gain access via ssh.

I am able to access the server via VNC.

OS: Centos 6.

Thank you.

Comment: ssh use port 22. Please clarify

Comment: Sorry for! It is port 22

Answer (score 0):

Why are you ssh’ing on port 21? That’s the ftp port (unless you manually changed it).

What port did you configure Squid to run on?

It sounds like one of the following has happened:

- you typoed port 22 for ssh
- you’ve overloaded a port (ie, are trying  to run more than one service on the same port)
- you turned ssh off

You say you can get to your server via virtual console. Check to see what services are configured to run on startup:

```
chkconfig --list | grep ’:on’
```

Is ssh listed? Check `/etc/sshd/sshd.conf` for what port it's configured to listen on.

Check to see what is holding port 22 (default ssh port) open:

```
netstat -an | grep 22
lsof -i:22
```

Check to see if sshd is even running:

```
ps aux | grep -i ssh
```

Check what port Squid is using by looking at `/etc/squid/squid.conf`

Lastly, you could refer to the Squid config I use on my proxy servers: https://antipaucity.com/2018/07/18/a-fairly-comprehensive-squid-configuration-for-proxying-all-the-http-things